# Recorrer ficheros en Python

Tags: python

Estoy tratando de hacer una parte de un programa en la cual te sale la tipica pantalla de iniciar sesión o crear cuenta. La parte de crear cuenta la tengo hecha, haciendo que la información del usuario se guarde en un fichero externo, sin embargo, a la hora de hacer la parte de inicio de sesión no sé como hacer para recorrer el fichero ya creado y comprobar si el usuario y contraseña que se hayan introducido pertenecen o no a algún usuario ya registrado en el fichero.

```
def crearFichero(nombre):
    fichero=open(nombre, "a")
    fichero.close()

def escribirFichero(nombre, linea):
    fichero=open(nombre, "a")
    fichero.write(linea)
    fichero.close()

def leerFichero(nombre):
    fichero=open(nombre, "r")

    for linea in fichero:
        linea.split(",")

    fichero.close()

#-----------CREAR CUENTA E INICIAR SESIÓN------------

opcion=input("Indique la opción que desea realizar: \n1)Iniciar sesión\n2)Crear cuenta\n")


if(opcion=="1"):

   print("INICIO DE SESIÓN:")
   usuario_comprobar=input("Nombre usuario:")
   password_comprobar=input("Contraseña:")
   leerFichero("Usuarios")


elif(opcion=="2"):

   crearFichero("Usuarios.txt")

   print("CREAR CUENTA:")
   nombre_usuario=input("Introduzca el nombre de usuario que desea: ")
   password=input("Introduzca una constraseña: ")

   escribirFichero("Usuarios.txt", "\n" + "Usuario:{}  Contraseña:{}".format(nombre_usuario, password))
```

Comment: ¿Qué clase de fichero? ¿un txt, base de datos, sql? Faltan datos. Rehaz la pregunta de manera que podamos entender que quieres hacer "exactamente".

Comment: Tendrías que especificar con qué estructura guardas los datos en el fichero. Por ejemplo, podría ser tipo "csv", en el que cada usuario es una línea y la información del mismo (nombre, contraseña, lo que sea) está separado entre sí por punto y coma. Un caso así es muy fácil de procesar, pues `for linea in fichero` te irá dando cada línea, y `linea.split(";")` dentro del bucle te permitiría separarla en sus campos.

Comment: @Saelyth en un principio estoy guardando los ficheros en modo txt

Comment: @abulafia...no sé manejar lo de split :(

Comment: Diego es necesario que agregues o bien el código con el que creas tu fichero o la estructura del mismo como te han comentado. Para poder obtener los distintos usuarios y separar nombre - contraseña es imprescindible conocer la estructura. Recorrer el fichero por líneas no tiene más misterio que `with open("usuarios.txt") as fichero: for linea in fichero: `, split simplemente retorna una lista resultado de dividir la cadena por un separador dado, `"Diego,12345".split(",")` nos retorna `["Diego", "12345"]`, por lo que podrías hacer `usuario, contraseña  = linea.split(",")`.

Comment: Ahora bien, ni siquiera sabemos si almacenas un usuario por línea  o no, si no es por líneas cómo separas unos usuarios de otros, cómo separas el nombre de la contraseña de un mismo usuario, etc. Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/184873/edit) y agrega la información necesaria a ella. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla ya he actualizado la pregunta. Sé por donde van los tiros pero no consigo acabar de encajarlo, la parte de ficheros siempre me cuesta muchisimo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tal y como estás generando tu fichero, los usuarios se van a almacenar uno por cada línea con el siguiente formato:

> ```
> Usuario:Diego  Contraseña:12345
> Usuario:Laura  Contraseña:abcdef
> Usuario:Alejandro  Contraseña:879abc
> ```

Sería conveniente que añadieras el carácter de nueva línea al final de la cadena, no al inicio como haces ahora, esto ocasiona una línea en blanco al inicio del fichero que puede dificultar innecesariamente el trabajo posterior.

Para **iterar sobre las líneas de un fichero** basta con iterar sobre él con un `for` como se ha comentado:

```
with open(ruta, "r") as fichero:
    for linea in fichero:
        # Procesar línea
```

Internamente esto se lleva a cabo mediante un iterador que llama a la implementación de la función `readline` hasta llegar al final del archivo. Hay que tener en cuenta que `readline` no elimina ningún espacio en blanco de la cadena, lo que incluye el carácter de fin de linea (`\n`, `\r\n`, `\r`), por lo que debemos eliminarlo dado el caso, por ejemplo mediante `str.strip("\r\n")` o mejor `str.rstrip("\r\n")`.

Con lo anterior claro, llega el problema de obtener los datos de cada línea, posiblemente sería mas simple usar un formato csv como comentaba @abulafia, alternativas hay muchas. En tu caso tienes varias opciones para parsearlo, por ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

- Eliminar el carácter de nueva línea como se ha comentado.  En tu caso un slicing que ignorara el último carácter también valdría, `linea[:-1]`.
- Eliminar `Usuario:` de la cadena, para ello podemos usar un simple rebanado o slicing de la cadena: `linea[8:-1]` obtendrá una nueva cadena a partir de la línea original descartando los primeros 8 caracteres y el último de la cadena.

  ```
   >>> "Usuario:Diego  Contraseña:12345\n"[8: -1]
   Diego  Contraseña:12345'
  ```
- Aplicar `str.split` sobre la cadena resultante del paso anterior usando `"  Contraseña:"` como separador, esto nos retornará una lista resultado de partir la cadena anterior por la subcadena `"  Contraseña:"`:

  ```
  >>> "Diego  Contraseña:12345".split("  Contraseña:")`
  ["Diego", "12345"]
  ```

  Puedes indexar sobre la lista para obtener cada dato o simplemente desempaquetarla:

  ```
  >>> usr, passw = "Diego  Contraseña:12345".split("  Contraseña:")`
  >>> usr
  'Diego'
  >>> passw
  '12345'
  ```

  Hecho esto basta con ir linea a línea comparando con lo que ha introducido el usuario.

Es decir, algo así:

```
def autentificar_usuario(ruta: str, usuario: str, password: str) -> bool:
    '''
    Retorna True si el usuario está en el archivo y
    la contraseña es correcta, False en caso contrario
    '''
    with open(ruta, "r") as fichero:
        for linea in fichero:
            nombre, contr = linea[8: -1].split("  Contraseña:", 1)
            if usuario == nombre and password == contr:
                return True
        return False
```

Ahora bien, lo anterior es útil si quisieras validar usuario y contraseña por separado, listar los pares usuario: contraseña del fichero, etc. Si solo quieres saber si ese usuario con esa contraseña está en el fichero es más simple generar la cadena correspondiente para lo ingresado por el usuario y comparar directamente las líneas:

```
from pathlib import Path


def guardar_usuario(ruta: str, usuario: str, password: str):
    line = gen_line(usuario, password)
    with open(ruta, "a") as fichero:
        fichero.write(line)

def autentificar_usuario(ruta: str, usuario: str, password: str) -> bool:
    line = gen_line(usuario, password)
    with open(ruta, "r") as fichero:
        for file_line in fichero:
            if line == file_line: 
                return True
        return False

def gen_line(usuario: str, password: str) -> str:
    line = "Usuario:{}  Contraseña:{}\n".format(usuario, password)
    return line


#-----------CREAR CUENTA E INICIAR SESIÖN------------

file = Path("Usuarios.txt")
file.touch(exist_ok=True)

opcion = input(("Indique la opción que desea realizar:\n"
                "1)Iniciar sesión\n"
                "2)Crear cuenta\n"
               ))

if opcion == "1":
    print("INICIO DE SESIÓN:")
    usuario = input("Nombre usuario: ")
    password = input("Contraseña: ")
    if autentificar_usuario(file, usuario, password):
        print("Autentificación exitosa")
    else:
        print("Lo siento, el usuario o contraseña no son correctos")

elif opcion == "2":
   print("CREAR CUENTA:")
   nombre_usuario = input("Introduzca el nombre de usuario que desea: ")
   password = input("Introduzca una contraseña: ")
   guardar_usuario(file, nombre_usuario, password)
```

Observa que en tu código creas el fichero solo cuando se ingresa la opción 2, si el usuario tratara de "iniciar sesión" sin que se hubiera ejecutado la opción 2 previamente tendrías una excepción porque el fichero no existe. Debes por tanto crear el fichero antes, o bien comprobar la existencia del archivo o manejar la excepción en la función encargada de validar.

> La cláusula `with` permite hacer uso del gestor de contextos, en este caso básicamente cierra el fichero automáticamente de forma segura a la salida del bloque, aun cuando se produzca una excepción durante la ejecución del mismo.